# Cannot use == with livedata<int> and int, how else can i check?

Tags: android, repository, android-room, android-livedata

ok so I have an android app and have followed androids room with a view tutorial. I have managed to get it working as expected with my recyclerview to show a history of all games played. I am now working on an achievements style page and want to check for specific scores achieved.

In my DAO file I have the following;

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from SavedScores WHERE difficulty = :Difficulty AND questioncount = :QuestionCount AND answeredcorrectly =:QuestionCount")
    fun CheckRecordsForTrophy(Difficulty: String,QuestionCount:Int):Flow<Int>
```

Then in my room repository I have this;

```
val easy5: Flow<Int> = savedScoresDao.CheckRecordsForTrophy("Easy",5)
```

In my view model;

```
val easy5: LiveData<Int> = repository.easy5.asLiveData()
```

and then in an activity I have the following;

Before the oncreate method:

```
private val savedScoresViewModel: SavedScoresViewModel by viewModels {
        SavedScoresViewModelFactory((application as ScoreApplication).repository)
    }
```

Within the oncreate method:

```
var easy5var = savedScoresViewModel.easy5

        savedScoresViewModel.easy5.observe(this) {
            if(easy5var==0){}

    }
```

I am not 100% sure if I should be following all these steps like I did to get all data into my recycler view but I have effectively followed the same steps with exception of adapters etc as I am simply trying to understand if they have met the criteria for a given achievement.

I have a hard coded elements in my repo at the moment for the function i.e CheckRecordsForTrophy("Easy",5) which I will figure how to set from the activity later

The issue I appear to be facing is with:

```
if(easy5var==0){}
```

**The error I get is Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'LiveData' and 'Int'.**

Goal: Check if within my score table is there a record where the score is equal to the number of questions asked, if so I will mark an achievement as complete. I have read that using count* in the query returns the number of records found so I can use that to work out if they should get the achievement or not. In other words, if no records, no achievement.

Comment: Can you post a stack trace of your error?

Comment: @IvanGarza just to confirm do you mean attempt build and share logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing an `Int` to a `LiveData`, when you probably wanted to compare the int to the emitted value of the live data.

```kotlin
var easy5var = savedScoresViewModel.easy5

savedScoresViewModel.easy5.observe(this) { newValue -> // this is what you've missed
    // if(easy5var==0) {} <-- you've made the wrong equality check here
    if (newValue == 0) {} // <-- probably this is what you've meant to do.

}
```

Comment: thank you very much. altered it as you suggested and ran the app and it is correctly identifying the count (to test it I just output the value to a text field) and after running another game it increased so your alteration was top notch